# Setting up httpd.conf for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, apache2

I'm trying to move a Rails app from Heroku to Amazon EC2, and I've never worked on a server before let alone on Linux or using Apache.  Along with Apache, I'm using the Thin gem.  I tried to configure my httpd.conf, like I read [here], but it only shows an "Index of/" page that is showing the files in the directory (my static error pages and favicon), which is not how I normally see my app (the root is set to another view).[1](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_tutorial_example_writing_and_deploying_a_hello_world_wsgi_application)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/myapp/public
  <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/myapp/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Did I declare my app incorrectly in the httpd.conf file?  I realize that I'm pointing directly to the public directory, while my normal root is Pages#index, but everywhere I've seen the configuration for Rails in the httpd.conf file seem to point to the public directory.

I figure it must be with how I configured the file since my app starts on the correct page on Heroku and locally.

Comment: Is that `VirtualHost` container in `httpd.conf` or `httpd-vhosts.conf`? Do you have other virtual hosts?

Comment: It's in httpd.conf.  That's the only virtual host I have.

Comment: No, that's the only one.  I just double checked

Comment: And you've uncommented `NameVirtualHost *:80`?

Comment: Apache alone can't handle Rails apps. It needs an application server like `passenger`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here before configuring Apache conf files. You will need passenger in order to run your rails app. If you have Rails installed you can do that on Ubuntu using rvmsudo as follows.

```
xyz@superGLTS:~$ rvmsudo gem install passenger
xyz@superGLTS:~$ rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Make sure to use rvmsudo as it will consider all your Rails env vars.

If this fails post the output of the error as it is likely you may need to install additional supporting libraries.

Then we can come back to your conf file once you have an Application server for your Rails app.

EDIT1: If the Passenger install failed on a newer install of Ubuntu then you may need to install build-essential as follows:

```
xyz@spuerGLTS:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

EDIT2:

The error you're now getting is a permissions issue on tmp/cache. The User:Group running your web server has to own or be able to write to that directory structure tmp/cache/.... In the httpd.conf you post on Git you have daemon:daemon running your web server. That's your problem. You can probably fix it quickly by chowning tmp/cache to daemon:daemon, but that's kind of half baked. You should create a user:group for this sole purpose and then correctly configure environment.rb, It's been a while, but there should be a section on user config and setting up permissions in the Passenger Guide

Comment: I tried installing Passenger yesterday, but the installation failed when I did passenger-install-apache2-module.  It had an error about the datess being in the incorrect format, I tried a couple of times (here's the log: https://gist.github.com/ryanchin/5049845).  So I was trying with Thin instead of Passenger.

Comment: Does Thin iunstall correctly? Also, please paste more of your Apache2 configuration if possible. In Ubuntu you may need to install additional headers, libraries and configuration. Please see my edits above

Comment: I managed to get Passenger installed, and when I run `passenger-memory-stats`, I see PassengerWatchdog, PassengerHelperAgent, PassengerLoggingAgent and Passenger RackApp all running. However, when I go to the IP, I get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." page. In the Apache2 logs: "ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied - /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/tmp/cache/76F):". I ran `chown -R bitnami:bitnami path/to/app` and all of the files for the app changed to this user, but I'm still getting this access error.  I also ran chmod 775 and 755 -R on my app directory. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: In case you still wanted to see my httpd.conf contents, I put them here: https://gist.github.com/ryanchin/5054673 .  Since I didn't know exactly what to do with the file, I left the existing contents so it's fairly long.